# Bind to escape sequence

Tags: bash

I can create a key binding in `~/.inputrc`

```
"qq": "rr"
```

this will insert `rr` any time I enter `qq`. However what if instead I want to insert an escape sequence?

```
printf '\ec'
```

will clear the screen and buffer, but if I use

```
"qq": "\ec"
```

it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not ideal, but does work

```
"qq": "printf '\\ec'\n"
```

[How do you configure .inputrc so ALT+UP has the effect of cd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9664)